# Form Not Populating in SQL Database

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I am trying to populate some data from a php form into a sql database when the user selects submit. However, the 'animalClass' and 'animalCommon' data is not populating; however the other data is populating fine. First I will post the HTML/PHP code and then some screen shots of the SQL db. Thank you for looking and the assistance.

```
$db = get_db_connection('swcrc');
    $db->connect();

    //Process status update form if submitted
    if(isset($_GET['admin_update']) && isset($_POST['request_id']) && 
       isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] != '')
    {
        $db->query("UPDATE dbo.Request SET status='%s' WHERE ID=%d", 
            $_POST['status'], 
            $_POST['request_id']);
        $db->query("INSERT INTO dbo.Response (request_ID, user_ID, complete, comment, response_date, animalClass, animalCommon) VALUES (%d, %d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
            $_POST['request_id'], 
            $_POST['status_update_user_id'], 
            $_POST['status'], 
            $_POST['status_update_comments'],
            $_POST['date_completed'],
            $_POST['animalClass'],
            $_POST['animalCommon']);
        $msgs = "Status updated successfully.";
        $mode = "readonly";
    }
    //Process admin update form if submitted
    else if(isset($_POST['request_id']) && isset($_POST['completed']) && $_POST['completed'] != '')
    {
        $db->query("UPDATE dbo.Request SET status='%s' WHERE ID=%d", 
            $_POST['completed'], 
            $_POST['request_id']);
        $db->query("INSERT INTO dbo.Response (request_ID, user_ID, complete, comment, response_date, animalClass, animalCommon) VALUES (%d, %d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
            $_POST['request_id'], 
            $_POST['completed_by_user_id'], 
            $_POST['completed'], 
            $_POST['not_completed'],
            $_POST['date_completed'],
            $_POST['animalClass'],
            $_POST['animalCommon']);
        $msgs = "Details updated successfully.";
```

Next I will post the select statement code:

```
<p>
<label for="animalClass">Class</label>
<select id = "animalClass" name="animalClass">
<option>Select a Class:</option>
<option value="Amphibians">Amphibians</option>
<option value="Birds">Birds</option>
<option value="Cnidarians">Cnidarians</option>
<option value="Fish">Fish</option>
<option value="Invertebrates">Invertebrates</option>
<option value="Mammals">Mammals</option>
<option value="Reptiles">Reptiles</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="animalCommon">Common Name</label>
                          <select name="animalCommon" id="animalCommon">
                            <option>Select a Common Name:</option>
                         <?php
$db = get_db_connection('swcrc');
$db->connect();
$db->query("SELECT [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals");
while($row = $db->fetch())
{
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['Common Name'];?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
                            </select>
                            </p>

<p>
<label for="animalScientific">Scientific Name</label>
                          <select name="animalScientific" id="animalScientific">
                            <option>Select a Scientific Name:</option>
                         <?php
$db = get_db_connection('swcrc');
$db->connect();
$db->query("SELECT [Scientific Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals");
while($row = $db->fetch())
{
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['Scientific Name'];?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
                            </select>
                            </p>
```

And finally here is a snap shot of my results in my sql database. Thank you again for looking and hopefully answering. The issue that you will see in the picture is the empty spaces where the selected data should be populated.
[image: As you can see, nothing is populating the the third and second to last columns.]

[image: Form]

Comment: I'm curious, why `SELECT [Common Name]` and `SELECT [Scientific Name]` ? If you're actually using that syntax, am not entirely sure that's valid. And if that's your colum names and contain spaces, then you should be using backticks instead of brackets.

Comment: The brackets work fine, I have tested them all in SQL and they pull my desired information. For some reason if I use anything but the brackets I do not get any information pulled. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Testing in SQL and on a LIVE server are not the same animal. Syntax is a bit different.

Comment: When I SELECT "Common Name" it pulls all the different common name's from the "Common Name" column.

Comment: Hahaha, I like the 'same animal' pun. I'll give the back tics a try and report back promptly.

Comment: hehe, yeah I kinda like it myself. Backticks are used whenever a column name contains spaces, or if a reserved word is used for either a table or a column.

Comment: However, I am still unsure why the values picked from 'animalClass' are not being populated since these are just hardcoded in html.

Comment: For some reason the program doesn't like the back tics. The brackets seem to populate the data just fine. I am still unsure as to why the data is not being written into the SQL table.

Comment: This doesn't look right to me `VALUES (%d, %d,....')",$_POST['request_id']` --- `$_POST['request_id']` should resemble `'$request_id',` etc.

Comment: The way the animals sql table was designed has been a pain, I was given the database in Access and had to bring it in to sql.

Comment: ... Taking into consideration that they are pre-defined variables. I.e.: `$request_id=$_POST['request_id'];` etc.

Comment: From Access to Web. Oh Lordie, now THAT's a completely different ball of wax, ouch.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: So it should look like VALUES ('$request_id', etc)", $_POST['request_id'], etc...);

Comment: Oh Lordie, MSSQL and MySQL are a bit different in certain ways. I'm not proficient enough with MSSQL to give you any definite answers. At first, I thought you were using MySQL, but when you mentioned ACCESS, that's where `bells went off`. Ok, well... at this point in time, it would be best for you to maybe Google this a bit further, and see if MSSQL versus MySQL use the same syntax for the VALUES. In MySQL, it's done the way I showed you previously. They don't use direct `$_POST` values, but the variables instead wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: Ok sounds good thanks for the help. Just as an update if in the VALUES ('%s', etc...) if I enter VALUES ('animalClass', etc...) the sql database receives the string animalClass in the correct column. Not correct animalClass (i.e mammals, etc) but the actual string 'animalClass'. Which is good that it passes that I am just not sure why I cannot pass in a variable to that position that reads from the select statement.

Comment: You're welcome. Try using `$db->query("INSERT INTO dbo.Response (request_ID, user_ID, complete, comment, response_date, animalClass, animalCommon) VALUES (%d, %d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')");` without `$_POST['request_id'],` etc. Doesn't seem right to me seeing that you have `(%d, %d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')` for VALUES, then a comma, then `$_POST['request_id'],` etc.